# Error: Data writes to account failed: RPC error: ClientError

Tags: solana-program, rust, solana-cli

I am trying to deploy solana rust program on the devnet and local net but I am getting error.

```
system$ solana program deploy /opt/projects/demo/rust-demo/anchor-escrow/target/deploy/anchor_escrow.so

Blockhash expired. 5 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 4 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 3 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 2 retries remaining
Blockhash expired. 1 retries remaining

Error: Data writes to account failed: RPC error: ClientError
```

Please let me know the issue and suggest solution for it.

Comment: I am able to build the program, airdrop some token. But unable to deploy using `anchor deploy`

Comment: Now I am getting error as 
`Error: Data writes to account failed: RPC error: ClientError { request: Some(GetBlockHeight), kind: Reqwest(reqwest::Error { kind: Status(503), url: Url { scheme: "http", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("api.devnet.solana.com")), port: None, path: "/", query: None, fragment: None } }) }`

Comment: same - did anyone find a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the lates sdk from [here](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools) and it is resolved

```
solana --version                                                            
  solana-cli 1.14.12
```